# A different title in one page in ASP.NET MVC without creating another master page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

In my master page I define the title of the page as follows:

```
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /><%= "- MyWebSite". %></title>
```

and then on every view I have something like:

```
<asp:Content ID="Title" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
  Products
</asp:Content>
```

so that I always end up with the name of the website in the title, like "Products - MyWebSite".

But for one and only one page, the home page, I want only the name of the site, as in "MyWebSite". Ideally I would like that for every view that doesn't define a title, I just show the name of the site. The problems is that with my current code I end up with "- MyWebSite" as title.

Any ideas how to do this without a lot of duplication? Definitely not creating another template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put the `- MyWebSite` inside another `ContentPlaceHolder`, and make a `Content` control for it in the home page (only).

In the master page, you put something like

```
<title>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleSuffixContent" runat="server">
    - MyWebSite
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</title>
```

and while your products page remain

```
<asp:Content ID="Title" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
  Products
</asp:Content>
```

your home page would be something like:

```
<asp:Content ID="Title" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
  MyWebSite
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="TitleSuffix" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleSuffixContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

or even:

```
<asp:Content ID="Title" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
  MyWebSite
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="TitleSuffix" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleSuffixContent" runat="server">
  - Your place on the interwebs
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: My apologies, I don't know why I didn't accept it straight away.

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do it's simply remove `runat="server"` attribute in your head tag